# Visual Studio 2017 15.3 Dockerize Database Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, docker-compose, visual-studio-2017

Have Visual Studio 2017 (15.3) solution with two projects:

- An API written in ASP.NET Core 2 MVC
- Database Project

I was able to "dockerize" the MVC project easily (right click, add Docker support) but while trying to dockerize the Database project keep getting the error: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: stream`. My Google-fu is failing me; the [closest resource found is for Visual Studio 15.2](https://pleasereleaseme.net/continuous-delivery-with-containers-say-goodbye-to-iis-express-and-localdb-with-visual-studio-2017-docker-and-windows-containers/).

**How I've Setup Database Project So Far**

Added Dockerfile to root:

```
FROM microsoft/mssql-server-linux:latest
EXPOSE 1433
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
ENV MSSQL_TCP_PORT=1433

# Add Database project output from VS build process
RUN mkdir --parents /_scripts/generated
COPY ./_scripts /_scripts/
COPY ./_scripts/generated/*.sql /_scripts/generated/
# Add shell script that starts MSSQL server, waits 60 seconds, then executes script to build out DB (script generated from VS build process)
CMD /bin/bash /_scripts/entrypoint.sh
```

**Modified docker-compose.yml file to include new project**

```
version: '3'

services:
  webapp-api-service:
    image: webapp-api
    build:
      context: ./src/API
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  webapp-db-service:
    image: webapp-db
    build:
      context: ./src/Database
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**Modified docker-composeoverride.yml file to expose port for dev SSMS access**

```
version: '3'

services:
  webapp-api-service:
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
    ports:
      - "80"

  webapp-db-service:
    ports:
      - "1433"
```

**Here's the build output**

```
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(279,5): error : Value cannot be null.
2>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Sdks\Microsoft.Docker.Sdk\build\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Docker.Compose.targets(279,5): error : Parameter name: stream
2>Done building project "docker-compose.dcproj" -- FAILED.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of the override, merge the content in one docker-compsoe and see if it helps

Comment: @TarunLalwani I tried that along w/ other variations of compose files.My best guess is that the VS docker-compose runner uses information from the .csproj to build the API image but fails to pull information from the .dbproj to build the DB image. I've tried manually adding/mimicking values from .csproj to .dbproj with no progress.

Comment: I'm getting the same error on a solution with multiple docker containers that built fine on 15.2 but now fails with 15.3.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue yesterday. I just solved it by removing the build portion of the database service. I'll just have to build the database project manually for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a file named `AppType.cache` to `/obj/Docker` with content `AspNetCore` as a workaround.